# MySQL Query Where Variable is equal

Tags: php, mysql, soap

I have this code

```
//Php SOAP request //
    <?php echo $hotel->hotelCode?>
//MySQL query //
    <?php
    $DBTYPE = 'mysql';
    $DBHOST = 'localhost';
    $DBUSER = 'dbuser';
    $DBPASSWORD = 'pwd';
    $DBNAME = 'dbname';

    $link = mysql_connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD);
    mysql_select_db($DBNAME); 
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $Hotel_id=".'$hotel->hotelCode'."; 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT HotelName FROM Hotels where HotelCode=$Hotel_id");
    $results = mysql_query($sql);
    var_dump($results);
    ?>
```

But its returning bool(false)
I have extract the code with the php SOAP request, the hotel name i have it stored in a mysql db
Could you advise me where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT HotelName FROM Hotels where HotelCode=$Hotel_id");
```

I'm guessing that the hotel code is a string.  In that case, you need additional quotes:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT HotelName FROM Hotels where HotelCode = '$Hotel_id'");
```

Comment: Thanks. `    $link = mysql_connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD);
    mysql_select_db($DBNAME); 
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
 $hotelCame = print_r($hotel->hotelCode, true);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT HotelName FROM Hotels where HotelCode= '$hotelCode'", $link);
if(!$result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $hotelName = $row["HotelName"];
}

echo $hotelName; //use this wherever you want
    ?> `